# Firefox addon sdk : Get header's loading time

Tags: javascript, firefox, sdk, http-headers

I'm developing an addon for Firefox that watches and filters headers, displaying the one I'm interested by.

I need to get the header's loading time, and this is how I do it, which is quite brutal :

```
    function getHeaderInformations(httpHeader, count){
        timer.setTimeout(function() {
            try{
                //this fails until the header is totally in
                var httpStatus = httpHeader.responseStatus;
            }catch(errStatus){
                getHeaderInformations(httpHeader, ++count);
        }, 1/*milliseconde*/);
    }
```

Every milliseconds I test it, if it fails i reload it, else it means that we have the header's status so that it is all completed.

The problem is : I don't think it's a good way to get header's loading time. I never get the same value as HTTPfox, Live HTTP Header or the console, plus it's not reliable.

I've searched for such attributes on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel without succes.

I've been through HTTPfox's code, but I must say that I couldn't find how they had this information.

The question is : How can I get the header's loading time properly ?

Comment: use a promise to do this instead of manually using setTimeout

Comment: @charlietfl from what I've read, promises are good if you want to set an action depending on a result (success / fail), which is not my case. I will always have the same result, success. The problem is knowing how long it took for it to come to me.